# Sending result of while loop to header

Tags: php

I'm trying to send the reslut of my while loop to the header but I can't figure out a way to get it to work.

The echo will give me a result like this:
C7&A8&

But the header will give me this: http://localhost/webapp/admin.php?success=C7

```
$result = mysqli_query($DB, "SELECT * FROM booking WHERE itemID IN('$itemID1','$itemID2','$itemID3','$itemID4','$itemID5','$itemID6','$itemID7','$itemID8','$itemID9','$itemID10')");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $hylla= $row['Hyllplacering']. "&";
    echo $hylla;

}
header('location: /webapp/admin.php?success=' .$hylla);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work. Using this method gets rid of the extra `&` at the end of the query string.

By the way, make sure you aren't `echo`ing anything before the `header` is set, as the headers are already sent once something needs to be printed on screen.

```
$result = mysqli_query($DB, "SELECT * FROM booking WHERE itemID IN('$itemID1','$itemID2','$itemID3','$itemID4','$itemID5','$itemID6','$itemID7','$itemID8','$itemID9','$itemID10')");

$hyllaArray = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $hyllaArray[] = $row['Hyllplacering'];
}
header('location: /webapp/admin.php?success=' . implode('&', $hyllaArray));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the redirect outside while loop, once you redirect from inside while it has no mechanism to get rest of the $hylla to new URL.

```
$result = mysqli_query($DB, "SELECT * FROM booking WHERE itemID IN('$itemID1','$itemID2','$itemID3','$itemID4','$itemID5','$itemID6','$itemID7','$itemID8','$itemID9','$itemID10')");
$hylla="";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $hylla= $hylla.$row['Hyllplacering']. "&";
}
    echo $hylla;
    header('location: /webapp/admin.php?success=' .$hylla);
```